# How to scale multiple images with a for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, pygame

I'm trying to use a for-loop to iterate through a list of self classes. I want to give each one the same scale.

```
def __init__(self):    
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.image = pygame.image.load("Migue/m_normal.png")

    self.quieto = pygame.image.load("Migue/m_normal.png")
    self.andando = pygame.image.load("Migue/m_andando_normal.png")
    self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, sizenorm)
 
    states = [self.quieto, self.andando]

    for i in states:
        i = pygame.transform.scale(i, sizenorm)
```

This wont work, but I can achieve the result using this:

```
self.quieto = pygame.transform.scale(self.quieto, sizenorm) 
self.andando = pygame.transform.scale(self.andando, sizenorm)
```

The problem is that I have to make a lot of more states, and using that for loop would be shorter. However, it doesn't work like the lower example does. I don't know what's wrong with the loop.

Comment: Store the images in a list, not in separate variables.  If you must have the names, then use a dictionary instead: `self.images['quieto']`.

Comment: `i` simply is a seperate variable, modifying it wont'change the original. Try `states = [pygame.transform.rotate(i, ...) for i in [self.one, self.two, ...]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a list of the scaled objects and assign the elements of the list to the original attributes:

```py
states = [self.quieto, self.andando]
states = [pygame.transform.scale(i, sizenorm) for i in states]
(self.quieto, self.andando) = states
```

This can even be written in a single line

```py
(self.quieto, self.andando) = [pygame.transform.scale(i, sizenorm) for i in [self.quieto, self.andando]]
```

Alternatively, you can simply put the images in a list:

```py
filenames = ["Migue/m_normal.png", "Migue/m_andando_normal.png"]
self.states = [pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(n), sizenorm) for n in filenames]
```